# Car Rental in Ireland for under 25 year old

Tags: car-rentals, ireland, age-limits

Can a person aged 24 rent a car in Ireland? I have tried a number of car rental companies but all of them have a minimum age requirement of 25.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. However you need to find car companies willing to rent to under 25s. Some car companies have separate search areas for under 25s e.g. [Sixt](http://www.sixt.com/youngdriver) - I searched for Belfast Airport/Dublin Airport and it shows it had cars for under 25s.

You may have to pay a surcharge for being a young driver.

Comment: Of course, Belfast is in Northern Ireland, but searching for cars from Dublin airport also returns results as well :-)

Comment: @Edd I always get them mixed up. :(